# Simple linear regression where the exact measurement error is known

Tags: regression, measurement-error, predictor

I've been looking through a bunch of error-in-variables models, but I can't find one that matches what I'm looking for (if it exists).

I am trying to do a simple (univariate) linear regression where I know the exact measurement error for each independent variable. Deming/orthogonal regression is too imprecise and I can't use instrumental variables because I don't have any exogeneous variables. Are there any models out there where I can plug in some "weights" for the measurement error of the independent variable?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173227 might be of some help.